# Host multiple websites on AWS Auto-Scaling Group with EFS

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-web-services, apache2, aws-ec2

I hope this is a simple question.
Currently I have an Apache2 webserver on Ubuntu with multiple websites.
The basic structure of the Apache is

```
/etc
  /apache2
     /sites-available  --> the .conf files for the websites
     /sites-enabled    --> the enabled .conf file links for the websites
/var
  /www
    /html
      /sites-admin     --> the location of the websites code
```

My task is to create an auto-scaling group that will be adjusting with the load.
My thought is to mount an EFS drive under /var/www/html/efs_mount and store the websites code there

However, this creates two issues:

1. this approach does not accommodate adding websites as i will have to update AMI and launch template, as well as instance refresh every time I add a website
2. when adding the website configuration to `/etc/apache2/sites-available`, in order to enable it we run `a2ensite webiste.conf`. as in the issue #1 this requires an update to the AMI and launch template, as well as instance refresh

Is there a way to work around this issue?
I know there's an option to use code deploy with the in-place or replace approach. Are there any other options?

Thanks
Igal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was resolved by mounting EFS under `/mnt/efs/fs1`, setting the Apache root directory to `/mnt/efs/fs1/www/html`, and configuring bitbucket pipelines to trigger AWS CodeDeploy to deploy to the root directory and, as part of the script, run `sudo systemctl reload apache2`